# What makes moving objects (pointers) slower than moving 64bit integers (same size as pointer)?

Tags: c#, performance

I'm making a simple demo program to highlight the performance impact of memory layout when working with large amounts of data. The idea is to have an array of integers, and an array of objects that contain an integer, shuffle both arrays, then loop over both arrays and add up all the values to highlight the difference in speed because of cache misses in the array of objects.

What I did not expect however, is that even the shuffling would be slower. I'm working on a 64bit machine, so object pointers should be 64bit. Shuffling around 64bit integers or 64bit pointers shouldn't make a difference, right? The same amount of data is moved in both cases. But my measurements tell me that shuffling objects takes about 1.75x as long as shuffling the integers.

Here's an example of my measurements (Release settings):

```
initializing ints took   334ms 1x (baseline)
initializing objs took  1153ms 3.45x

shuffling ints took   409ms 1x (baseline)
shuffling objs took   721ms 1.76x
```

The initializing difference makes sense, since objects need to be allocated separately from the array and integers don't.

My main question is: What causes the performance difference for the *shuffling*?

My best guess is that it has to do with overhead from garbage collection, perhaps from reference counting? If that hunch is correct, I would really like a more in-depth answer about what exactly it is that the GC is doing. Perhaps there even is a way to move object references in such a way to avoid this overhead, for example when you know that the reference count won't change.

Here's the code I used for this demo. (I know Random isn't cryptographically safe and Stopwatch isn't the most accurate measurement, but I don't think that discredits my observations.)

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo; 
class Program {

    class Int_Obj {
        public Int64 value;

        public Int_Obj(Int64 val) { this.value = val; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        Int64[]   int_array;
        Int_Obj[] obj_array;

        const int array_size  = 10_000_000;
        
        init_arrays(out int_array, out obj_array, array_size, sw);

        shuffle_arrays(int_array, obj_array, sw);

        // ...
    }

    static void init_arrays(out Int64[] int_array, out Int_Obj[] obj_array, int size, Stopwatch sw) {
        int seed = Environment.TickCount; // same seed to fill both arrays with same values
        Random rand;

        rand = new Random(seed);
        sw.Restart();
        int_array = new Int64[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) int_array[i] = rand.NextInt64();
        sw.Stop();
        var ints_time = sw.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("initializing ints took {0,5:0}ms 1x (baseline)", ints_time.TotalMilliseconds);

        rand = new Random(seed);
        sw.Restart();
        obj_array = new Int_Obj[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) obj_array[i] = new Int_Obj(rand.NextInt64());
        sw.Stop();
        var objs_time = sw.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("initializing objs took {0,5:0}ms {1:0.##}x", objs_time.TotalMilliseconds, objs_time.Divide(ints_time));

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void shuffle_arrays(Int64[] int_array, Int_Obj[] obj_array, Stopwatch sw) {
        int seed = Environment.TickCount; // same seed to shuffle both arrays the same way

        sw.Restart();
        shuffle(int_array, new Random(seed));
        sw.Stop();
        var int_time = sw.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("shuffling ints took {0,5:0}ms 1x (baseline)", int_time.TotalMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();
        shuffle(obj_array, new Random(seed));
        sw.Stop();
        var obj_time = sw.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("shuffling objs took {0,5:0}ms {1:0.##}x", obj_time.TotalMilliseconds, obj_time.Divide(int_time));

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void shuffle<T>(T[] array, Random rand) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
            int r = rand.Next(i, array.Length);
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[r];
            array[r] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GC doesn't use reference counting, it uses recursive roots. And if you want proper benchmarks then you shouldn't use `Stopwatch`, use a proper benchmarking suite like BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel sorry, forgot to provide that one, I added it now

Comment: There's an extra CLR helper call involved with object assignments, named CORINFO_HELP_ASSIGN_REF.  Visible when you look at the machine code with Debug > Windows > Disassembly.  [This github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/76104) discusses it.